# How to use static variables in multiple instances of pivotal cloud foundry for same micro-service

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

I have a micro-service which is having multiple instances. The micro-service has a Spring scheduler which calls a particular method in the micro-service to update the static variable - this is similar to Authorization and once updated the final value of the variable is stored in the database. 
The issue is we have both instances trying to update the static variable, in the first instance the Authorization gets updated but in the second PCF instance since the Authorization is updated, when it tries to execute it fails as Authorization used was updated in the previous instance.

Is there any other alternative apart from fetching the static data from the database or storing the data in PCF environment variable?

Comment: Are the two instances running on the same machine? Are they running in the same JVM? Why is pivotal cloud foundry relavant?

Comment: PCF was relevant in answering the queries about instances. I believe in PCF when we choose to create multiple instances it should automatically assign a different JVM for each instance.

Comment: Can you explain more about why both instances are trying to update the variable?  PCF is going to route one request to one app instance.  If you're seeing requests hit both app instances, then you've got two requests being sent to your app.  If you can eliminate one of those then your problem should go away.